# cakephp setup to run first program

Tags: php, cakephp

I am in a little settings problem to make cakephp work for me.

I've created a folder named `Hello World` in the document root directory which is set to `C:\xampp\htdocs`. The Document root thus is `C:\xampp\htdocs\Hello World` into which I copy and paste all the downloaded unzipped cakephp13. However, when I run the browser with the url set as http://localhost/Hello World I am reported that

```
"HelloWorldController" could not be found Create the class
HelloWorldController below in file
app\Controler\HelloWorldController.php
```

Answer (score 0):

copy the folder "Cakephp13"  to root of XAmpp

then

in Browser

http://localhost/cakephp13/helloworld

// cakephp13 is missing in your URL.